# Trying to draw a circle in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d, render

this is really basic but I can't figure out what's going wrong. Basically I'm trying to draw a circle around a certain area of one of my objects. I've initialised a `ShapeRenderer` in the constructor (called *srDebugCircle*) and have this for loop in the `render()` method to draw every object.

```
for (GameObject object : levels.get(LEVEL_INDEX)) {
        if (object.getType() == ObjectType.SWINGING_SPIKES) {
            object.draw(batch);
            srDebugCircle.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
            srDebugCircle.circle(object.getxPos() + object.getWidth()/2, object.getyPos(), object.getWidth()/2);
            srDebugCircle.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            srDebugCircle.end();
        }

        if (object.getType() == ObjectType.COIN && (Coin) object).isVisible()) {
            object.draw();
        }
        ...
}
```

The problem is I only see like 4 out of 15 objects when I add the code for the circle. When I remove it / comment it it works as usual - however, in both cases, I can never see a black filled circle.

I'm specifically talking about this part:

```
            srDebugCircle.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
            srDebugCircle.circle(object.getxPos() + object.getWidth()/2, object.getyPos(), object.getWidth()/2);
            srDebugCircle.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            srDebugCircle.end();
```

Can anybody see why I'm having this problem?

Comment: I think you are missing a parenthesis between the quotes. Maybe not the cause though.(object.getType() == ObjectType.COIN && "("(Coin) object).isVisible())

Comment: You have to set the color before drawing the circle.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Springrbua’s answer is to draw using Pixmaps instead of ShapeRenderer. Switching between SpriteBatch and ShaperRenderer is an expensive operation and Pixmaps don’t require ending the SpriteBatch. Pixmap offers fewer draw methods than ShapeRenderer, but it does include drawing a filled circle.

```
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
pixmap.setColor(Color.BLACK);
pixmap.fillCircle(x, y, r);
Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap);

// render
batch.begin();
batch.draw(texture, x, y);
batch.end();
```

Comment: You should always pixmap.dispose() and texture.dispose() when after draw on screen for memory management

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that you have two `Renderer`/`Batch`es running at the same time:
The `SpriteBatch batch` and the `ShapeRenderer srDebugCircle`.
This can result in strange behaivor.
To solve the problem, call `end()` for one `Renderer`/`Batch` before calling `begin()` for the other.
In your case it would look something like this:

```
object.draw(batch);
batch.end()
srDebugCircle.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
srDebugCircle.setColor(Color.BLACK);    // Set Color before drawing
srDebugCircle.circle(object.getxPos() + object.getWidth()/2, object.getyPos(), object.getWidth()/2);
srDebugCircle.end();
```

Also note, that calling `end()` on a `SpriteBatch` calls `flush()` which should be called as rarely as possible. Therefore it might be a good idea to draw everything with the `SpriteBatch` and then draw all the `ShapeRenderer` things.